# Proving triangle congruence

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I have been tasked to prove the following: 
$$\triangle ABC \cong\triangle EDC $$
Give that $C$ is midpoint of $\overline{BE}$, and angles $\angle B $ and $\angle E$ are right angles. 
How would you approach in proving the congruence?
 [image: Triangles to be proved congruent]
P.S Drawing is not accurate representation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: you know the length of a side and two angles in both triangles.

$\angle B = \angle E$

$|BC|=|CE|$

Then you'll just need to argue that:
$\angle ACB = \angle ECD$

Answer (score 0):

Here, $$\angle ACB=\angle ECD~~~[\text{vertical angle}]$$
$$\angle ABC=\angle CED=90^{\circ}$$
$$BC=CE~~~[\text{As,C is the midpoint of BE}]$$
So,
$$\triangle ABC \cong\triangle EDC$$